# Center aligning text inside div - div has height in percentage

Tags: css, height

I am trying to vertical align the text in my quote inside the .black div. I have looked at other questions which said to give the same line-height as the height of the div. I think it's not working because the height of the div is a percentage, but no idea how to fix it.

```
.black {
background-color:#333333;
margin: 0px;
height: 20%;
line-height: 20%;
}

.quote {
font-family:Courier New, monospace;
font-style:italic;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}
```

Thanks very much, and I know the code is probably very ugly.

Comment: Did you tried to use `position: relative` and `position: absolute` ?

Comment: can you please add your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use flex on your .black class

```
.black {
   display: flex;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.black {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
       bottom: 0px;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }
```